# If I have the an id how to know in which page number?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

table in database

```
id

1  
2   
4  
30  
31
...
```

pagination

```
per page is 2 row, desc.
```

If I have the `id = 30` how to know in which page number?
Any suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Basic process: `select count(*) from your table where id <= 30` to figure out how many records come before your id, and then convert that to pages.

Comment: -1 for that silly cheating with deleting a question and asking it over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get its order:

```
select count(*) from table_name where id <= 30 order by col_name;
```

Then figure page number:

```
int order = 27; // the result from previous query,
int pageSize = 10;
int pageNum = order/pageSize + (order%pageSize==0?0:1); // here page number start from 1, not 0,
```